# Get post parameter before upload

Tags: java, file-upload, apache-commons

When I use Commons FileUpload the method parseRequest(request) uploads files and also reads additional post parameters. So I can get parameter values only after uploading the files.
The problem is that I need those parameter values before uploading the files (one of the parameters is upload_path).

Is there any way to get post parameters first from multipart content and then start uploading to the correct folder?

(request.getParameter(name) will return null for multipart content).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me, in first pass I check all parameters, after that I take the non form fields for download.

```
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator( request );

while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
    FileItemStream item = iter.next();
    String name = item.getFieldName();
    InputStream stream = item.openStream();

    if ( item.isFormField() ) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[ 128 ];
        int len = stream.read( buffer );
        String value = new String( buffer, 0,len );
        if ( name.equals( "name" ) ) {
            filename  = value;
        }
        System.err.println( "Form field " + name + " with value " + value + " detected." );
        stream.close();
    }
}
```